# if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) don't work

Tags: android, if-statement, conditional-statements, nfc

I trying to make a NFC APP with Android Studio but the `if` condition doesn't work

```
private void readForIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action=intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            ||NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            ||NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Tag tag;
        tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (tag != null) {
            handleNfcIntent(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can tell me where is the error.

Comment: What is your `intent.getAction()` value? What do you mean by your condition doesn't work?

Comment: When I scan the NFC tag, the value of intent.getAction() is null, so the condition NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) is false, the same happen with the rest